# duplicate object in array angular

Tags: angular

I am having issue of duplicate check before adding the object to an array. For some reason, the check always returns -1 and hence duplicate objects are getting added. What is the problem here ?

```
  export interface StressTestAnalysis extends GraphConfiguration {

    curlevel: number;
    decrease: number;
    increase: number;
    yaxis: number[];
    data: number[];
    seriesName: string;
    color: string;
}


 public results: Array<StressTestAnalysis> = [];

@Input() set stressResults(value: Array<StressTestAnalysis>) {
    this._stressResults = value;
    this.addSeries();
    let minY = Math.min(...this.yAxisSeries.map(el => Math.min(...el.yaxis)));
    let maxY = Math.max(...this.yAxisSeries.map(el => Math.max(...el.yaxis)));
    this.generateYAxisArray(minY, maxY);

  }


this.results =  this._stressResults.map((result: any) => {

      var index = this.results.findIndex(item => item.seriesName === result.data.seriesName);

      if (index > -1) {
      result.chartSeries =  this.chartSeries.push({ data: result.data, name: result.seriesName, color: result.color });
      result.yAxisSeries = this.yAxisSeries.push({ yaxis: result.yaxis });
      }
      return result;
    });
```

Comment: You are trying to access the `result` inside the `map` which hasn't been updated with new values, so it is adding the duplicate result. Instead of `array#map` use `array#reduce`.

Comment: So do you mean using array reduce will avoid duplicates itself and i dont need to do a condition check

Comment: No, `array#reduce` will let you access the intermediate result which isn't possible with `array#map`, you will still need to check for the duplicate value.

Comment: I have this method but the problem with this method is that it does not return of type results which is of type StressTestAnalysis

Comment: var results = this._stressResults.reduce((r, o) => {
      if (o.data) r.chartSeries.push({ data: o.data, name: o.seriesName, color: o.color });
      if (o.yaxis) r.yAxisSeries.push({ yaxis: o.yaxis }); 
      return r;
    }, 
    { chartSeries: [], yAxisSeries: [] })

Comment: You are not checking for the unique object here.

Comment: I have two issues here. I dont know how to use reduce. How do I check for unquieness here and also have the return type of StressTestAnalysis

Comment: Can you share the class `StressTestAnalysis`?

Comment: Sure. Updated the post

Comment: why do you use map? it's not better use forEach?

Comment: I tried this forEach but it is still adding duplicate  this._stressResults.forEach(element => {
      var index = this.results.findIndex(item => item.seriesName === element.seriesName);
      if (element.data !== null && index > -1)
          this.chartSeries.push({ data: element.data, name: element.seriesName, color: element.color });
       if (element.yaxis !== null && index > -1)
        this.yAxisSeries.push({ yaxis: element.yaxis });
    });

    this.results = this._stressResults;